# How to setup your own MQTT-S server on Raspberry Pi2 board using Mosquitto or othr broker

Tags: mqtt, broker, raspberry-pi2

this is my first project and i m facinated by MQTT -S comparison with HTTP and MQTT. now, i intend to creat my own server over Raspberry PI2 board. I m using TIVA C launchpad for communicating the signals with Raspberry via Ethernet. but truth is is Im new to Rpi and MQTT-S.
can you please suggest the basic tutorials or steps how to make my Own server and how to test it. i m good with Hardware and Sensor and all other  programming within board is done(TIVA C series Launch pad).

please suggest me some links, video tutorials or steps how to proceed.
I have read http://mqtt.org/new/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/MQTT-SN_spec_v1.2.pdf
and it looks alot easy and have watch few videos by IBM as well.
but , i lack the confidence that i can do it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not allowed to comment on Michael's response because I don't have enough points; but his answer looks pretty complete.

I use RSMB as my MQTT-SN server, using the sources from Eclipse:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/mosquitto/org.eclipse.mosquitto.rsmb.git

I followed the instructions here:
http://modelbasedtesting.co.uk/?p=44

And here is a simple MQTT-SN configuration, running on UDP port 1883:
https://gist.github.com/njh/1d3c76b55719910263ca

Comment: Those instructions also helped me at beginning.

Answer (score 1):

If you want mqtt-sn broker try RSMB. [Official RSMB repository is here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/mosquitto/org.eclipse.mosquitto.rsmb.git).

Little bit better mqtt-sn support is in this [alternative RSMB fork](https://github.com/MichalFoksa/rsmb).

Whichever you choose clone git repository to your Raspberry, build it and configure. Documentation is in [gettingstarted.htm](https://rawgit.com/MichalFoksa/rsmb/master/rsmb/doc/gettingstarted.htm). The documentation is s clear. If you are running Raspbian you should have all necessary components to build it.

You can also install Mosquitto - I do not know how far is mqtt-sn support there. [Here you are instructions](http://jpmens.net/2013/09/01/installing-mosquitto-on-a-raspberry-pi/).

I suggest you the alternative RSMB fork, but to be honest I am associated with this fork.

Nicholas Humfrey made handy [mqtt-sn client utility](https://github.com/njh/mqtt-sn-tools), or use client from Mosquito.

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry i missed to write that it can be any broker. I used mosquito to clear for example related to brokers. 
All i want to try is publish and then subscribe my data. (later test it as well)

Comment: HI Mike, i m done with the code till some extent, can you please tell me the procedure how to dump this code in raspberry pi board?

Comment: Hi Sachin. What does it mean "dump this code in raspberry"?

Comment: Mike, sorry about that.. i ll first dump the rsmb and mqtt-sn and will see how my raspberry behave for the this code. And will revert for any update. Currently i m stuck with Tiva C code.